# Instantiate not showing object

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get a object to spawn at mouse position in unity 2d
whenever I click, but none of the objects are showing. It adds new clones in the hierarchy, but just not showing.

Here Is the script for the game controller object

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class gamecon : MonoBehaviour
{
   
    public GameObject square;
   
    public void Start()
    {
    
    
    }
        
    
    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            
            Vector3 spawnpos = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(Input.mousePosition);
            
            GameObject g =Instantiate(square, (Vector2)spawnpos, Quaternion.identity);
        }

    }

}
```

I cant find any answers on the web that apply to my situation.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use the [ScreenToWorldPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.ScreenToWorldPoint.html) method and not the [WorldToScreenPoint](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Camera.WorldToScreenPoint.html) because what you need is the world position to spawn your object.

Use the following code:

```
public void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        
        Vector3 spawnpos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
        
        GameObject g =Instantiate(square, (Vector2)spawnpos, Quaternion.identity);
    }

}
```